# Can't find out how button click event got wired

Tags: debugging, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I have a button which posts back through Ajax. I tried to find out what code executes when the button is clicked. I used Visual Event (screen capture below) to see how the event was bound but the info didn't help me enough. Then I set an event listener breakpoint on mouse clicks in Chrome. The breakpoint hit code in the main jQuery file which was also not helpful. So I blackboxed the file. Now when I click the button, no breakpoints are hit.

What's a systematic way to find the user code which gets executed? I also searched for 'live' and 'click' as text across the whole app. It was time consuming and didn't find where the click event for the button got attached. It's painful to do such a search. I would like to know the productive technique using Chrome's debugger or another tool. (Another browser's tips are OK)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Chrome profiler?

1. Launch the Chrome DevTools (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Go to the *Profiles* panel
3. Ensure that *Collect JavaScript CPU Profile* is selected
4. Click *Start*
5. Perform your operation
6. Click *Stop*.

Then you should see a list of functions that were called.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible ways to do so. One is described by the user thesentiment. Another way is to use the DevTools' debugger.

1. Open the Chrome DevTools (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Switch to the *Sources* panel
3. Click the *Pause* button ([image: Pause script execution button]) or hit <kbd>F8</kbd>
4. Perform your operation

=> The script execution will stop at the first line of the event handler function within jQuery. You can then step through to your actual event handling function.

Note that in Firebug this works much easier, because its [*Events* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Events_Side_Panel) already displays the wrapped listeners, i.e. the functions that are called by a jQuery event listener:

[image: Wrapped event listeners within Firebug's *Events* side panel]

Comment: If this is different than stepping through a ton of jQuery code until I reach the user's code, then that could be beneficial and I will try it next time. I was expecting that when I blackbox jQuery, it skips all the jQuery code and a breakpoint hits the user's code. That didn't happen.

Comment: If that's the case, then I'd expect it to be a bug in the DevTools, which you should report.